# Why do my simple HTTP server implemented with Boost.ASIO needs sleep to work correctly

Tags: c++, networking, boost, boost-asio

I'm trying to write a very simple HTTP server using Boost.Asio. Here is the code (almost the same as the example from Boost.Asio tutorial)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

int main()
{
    try
    {
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;

        tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 12345));

        for (;;)
        {
            tcp::socket socket(io_service);
            acceptor.accept(socket);

            const char message[] = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n\r\n<html><body><i>Hello, world</i></body></html>";

            boost::system::error_code ignored_error;
            boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(message), ignored_error);
        }
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this sample, I try with Chrome at address 127.0.0.1:12345, but it shows "This webpage is not available". But if I start in a debugger and step by step, it correctly displays the italicized "Hello, world". In fact, it will work correctly if I add a line `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));` after the write operation. What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to avoid this ugly hack?

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 7. Compiled as 64 bit code.

Comment: Come back tomorrow and you'll have the answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the problem is an `HTTP` issue not a networking issue.

The message lacks a `Content-Length` header and so your `HTTP/1.1` client (Chrome) is probably waiting for your server to close the connection to mark the end of the message body, see: [rfc2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html) section 4.4. Try changing the message to:

```
  "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: 45\r\n\r\n<html><body><i>Hello, world</i></body></html>";
```

I hope I've got the `Content-Length` of your message body right. ;)

Comment: Sounds plausible, indeed. +1

Comment: This works on my Mac, but not on my work machine which has Windows 7 installed. Completely baffled now.

Comment: `HTTP` comms is not quite as simple as it at first appears. I started creating a C++ library for an HTTP server over a year ago and it's only now that I believe that it's anywhere near complete! It's at [via-httplib](https://github.com/kenba/via-httplib), it's got some simple examples similar to yours above. Please feel free to try it out and see if it can fix your problem.

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

The idea that Content-Length maybe required by the client could have some merit.

Conversely, you could add a `Connection: close` header, which would prevent the browser from keeping it open (hence 'EOF' would count as end of response).

---

The code looks fine and it works without sleep on my box (Ubuntu/Opera).

The only things that strikes me as... interesting is that

- you are sending the terminating `NUL` character as part of the response:

  ```
  $ netcat localhost 12345 | xxd
  0000000: 4854 5450 2f31 2e30 2032 3030 204f 4b0d  HTTP/1.0 200 OK.
  0000010: 0a0d 0a3c 6874 6d6c 3e3c 626f 6479 3e3c  ...<html><body><
  0000020: 693e 4865 6c6c 6f2c 2077 6f72 6c64 3c2f  i>Hello, world</
  0000030: 693e 3c2f 626f 6479 3e3c 2f68 746d 6c3e  i></body></html>
  0000040: 00                                       .
  ```
- you are not receiving the request; depending on the client this might confuse the client a little (?). I don't think this can be the problem here because there's precious little request information to be split up into packages

**Update** Actually, the/a problem might occur if your browser does other requests (like `GET /favicon.ico`, e.g. in parallel. Your server handles connections synchronously and they might arrive simultaneously. Make sure that the listening socket allows for at least 1 (or maybe, say, 10) connections in the "backlog"

This [old answer ('08) says `backlog` used to be 5 in Asio, by default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/115263/85371).

Comment: I tried on my Mac. Chrome displays nothing instead of error.

Comment: And on Mac I still need to add the sleep hack to make it work.

Comment: @C.R. Updated with another idea based on connection keep-alive semantics.

Comment: The `Connection: close` sounds plausible, but it does not work. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are not waiting for the request.   If the socket is closed before the request is sent, the client will see this as a reset connection.   Your one second delay trick works because it keeps the connection open for long enough for the client to send through its request.

Your example works without the delay trick if I add a dummy request listener, just before the write:

```
std::array<char, 8192> ignored_buffer;
socket.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(ignored_buffer),
    [](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {});
```